# Python - How to group variables separated by or/and operators

Tags: python, operators

I am trying to find a way to make the following (sample) code more elegant:

```
if answer == "yes" or "Yes" or "Y" or "y" or "why not":
    print("yeah")
```

In the same manner there in english you would not say:

> The possible answers are yes or Yes or Y or why not.

and you would rather say:

> The possible answers are yes, Yes, Y or why not.

What would the more elegant way of doing this would be?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Just in case, I'm very new to Python, and I could not search thoroughly for dupes since I don't know how this is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option 1: `answer in ["yes", "Yes", "Y", "y", "why not"]` ... not a good idea, builds a list each time you run it.

Option 2: `answer in ("yes", "Yes", "Y", "y", "why not")` ... better idea, the (constant, immutable) tuple is built at compile time.

Option 3: do this once:

`allowables = set(["yes", "Yes", "Y", "y", "why not"])`

and then use `answer in allowables` each time you need it. This is the best approach when the number of allowable values is large, or the set of allowable values can vary at run-time.

Comment: @John, you are right, I did hurry to choose the correct answer. Sorry about that, it was mainly my ignorance of the language and the fact that I though the question was simple enough to be "completely" answered with this first answer. So, I apologize and thank you for you answer.

Comment: out of curiosity: you advise to use () in option 2, but use [] when forming the frozenset in option3? why?

Comment: @akira: (A) in option 3, building the sequence is done only once, so it doesn't matter (B) set((....)) seems to disturb the reader, set([....]) doesn't

Comment: @trufa you may want to use answer.lower() or answer.upper(), this makes it canse insensitive, so you can accept 'YEs', 'Why Not' and so on, `answer.lower() in ('yes', 'y', 'why not')`

Comment: @John Machin: (A) it matters .. only 'not that much' :), (B) how do you measure your disturbing claim? :)

Comment: @akira: (A) 'not that much' is vanishingly small (B) a structured sample of 2 devs, me and Pat Malone

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, I was aware of this (though not for python specifically) this is just an example, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`in` operator](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-bytes-bytearray-list-tuple-range) to compare against a list:

```
if answer in ["yes", "Yes", "Y", "y", "why not"]:
    print("yeah")
```

Comment: @Ben: One a little off (this) topic question, where could I read about  why (apparently now) you must use print("-") and not print "-"? Thanks, I did not want to start a question about that

Comment: @JeffM: I saw your answer and it was correct too, I thank you also!! but Ben was indeed the fastest gun!

Comment: @Jeff M — It's pure luck, sometimes. :-)

Comment: @Trufa — That's one of (few) major syntactic changes in Python 3 (a.k.a. Python 3000).  Personally, I'd start with [What's New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html), but I'm a sucker for reading the official docs rather than tutorials.  ;-)

Comment: @Trufa: the fastest gun is not always the best. Consider waiting and judicious assessing the answers ...

Comment: @Ben I apologize for taking the accepted answer "away from you". I was too quick and did not let the opportunity for more answers, I think [John's answer] is very complete and should be accepted ans the correct one. You have my +1, but sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Following code does the same thing:

```
if answer in ["yes", "Yes", "Y", "y", "why not"]:
    print "yeah"
```

Comment: For some reason, don't know why yet, I must use print("yeah") and not  print "yeah" since this won't work, is this true fot python's latest versions?

Comment: @Trufa: Apparently you are using python 3.  So in that case, `print` is now a function and no longer a statement.  That would explain why this wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Yes. print is a function in Python3.

Comment: @JeffM: Ok this explains it. Thanks!!